# Oracle Sql display condensed

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

so I am currently using Sql (oracle) and when I do certain select statements my display is condensed to the point where all my values are not aligned. I am not too sure if it's because I created my tables a certain way or if it has something to do with my screen size settings.

Here is an example picture:

[image: My sql display issue]

Comment: It's because the lines are too long, if you had more characters per line (in the console) it would display fine. Not an SQL problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just increased my line size and my display is great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example screenshot shows you using the sqlplus interface. It has various settings to display the information. For example, you can change the line size used by sqlplus by using the sqlplus `set linesize XXXX` command. You can change the width of the columns by using the sqlplus `column c1 format ...` command. Lots of flexibility within sqlplus for formatting. Check out the docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm